# "Pay for play" vs. "play for pay"

Tags: verbs, prepositions, word-order

We recently had a discussion whether "Pay for play" or "Play for pay" is the correct term to describe that you get money when you play.

Which one is correct to point out that you get paid for playing?

Comment: It depends on perspective: do you pay for bread, or does de baker bake for money? I write code for money, but my boss pays money for code. So if you play for money, you play for pay. But a viewer will pay for play.

Comment: It's about yourself being the person that plays and gets money, so play for pay would be correct?

Comment: Yes, like the baker bakes for pay, and I code for pay. If you change _pay_ to _money_, does your confusion still exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you play for pay, then you receive pay for play.

Are you focussing on the activity (play for pay) or the money (pay for play)?